# MySql: How quotes around date(string) affects the results?

Tags: mysql, sql

Difference between two queries marked with ^

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customers_reports AS cr 
JOIN customers_docs on customers_docs.customerId=cr.customerId 
WHERE cr.firstDepositDate >= 2015-12-01  AND customers_docs.docs = "None";
```

This query returns 2 results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customers_reports AS cr 
JOIN customers_docs on customers_docs.customerId=cr.customerId 
WHERE cr.firstDepositDate >='2015-12-01' AND customers_docs.docs = "None";  
                            ^          ^
```

While this query returns 30,000 results.

May someone explain why?

Comment: what is the datatype of `firstDepositDate`?

Comment: Does MySQL use double quotes for string literals? (According to ANSI SQL `"None"` is a column.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without single quotes the date value becomes the arithmetic expression and 2015-12-01 is 2002 which is obviously affect the result

Answer (score 2):

Because when you do not quote the date, MySQL thinks it's an integer.

`2015-12-01` evaluates to `2002`.